# miss button click event when button is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

have the following headache: there is a knockout viewmodel with initialize function

```
initialize: function () {
// bla bla
     this.toolbar.addButton({ text: 'View All', label_key: 'view_all', click: 'viewAll' });
},
```

and some handler-functions

```
viewAll: function () {
     this.toolbar.removeButton('#view_all');
     this.toolbar.addButton({ text: 'View Users Projects', label_key: 'view_users_projects', click: 'viewUsersProjects' });
    //some things to do
    });

viewUsersProjects: function () {
   localstorage.clear()// I need this here but this function doesn't work
    this.toolbar.removeButton('#view_users_projects');
    });
}
```

So, the problem is following - when button viewAll is clicked - the same function works BUT if button viewUsersProjects is clicked viewUsersProjects function doesn't work, it moves straight off to initialize, I even can delete viewUsersProjects function and nothing is changed but view_users_projects button is disappeared somehow... What I need actually to clear localstorage when view_users_projects button  is clicked. Appreciate your answers.

the prototype functions for add/remove buttons:

```
_.extend(Toolbar.prototype, {
    addButton: function (options) {
        $('.navbar ul.nav:eq(0)').append(
            '<li class="kkvw-button" id="' + options.label_key + '">' +
                '<a data-bind="click: ' + options.click + '" href="">' +
                '</a>' +
            '</li>'
        );

        return this;
    },

    removeButton: function (text) {
        $(text).remove();
    },
});
```

Comment: What happens in the `addButton`/`removeButton` functions? If these do immediate DOM-operations which knockout isn't aware of then knockout can't bind anything to the button (since knockout isn't aware of the DOM-alterations).

Comment: It is impossible to reliably help you without being able to reproduce your scenario. We need more code for that. Please consider creating a Stack Snippet, or at the very least adding more code to your question.

Comment: @RobertWesterlund I've addButton/removeButton code. So, what can you recommend?

Comment: Thank you all. The trouble was really in the fact that there was no binding of click event. I've done with the help of jquery